# Amazon DynamoDB chooses Consistency during a network partition. What does Amazon Document DB do?

Tags: mongodb, amazon-web-services, couchdb, cap-theorem

Amazon DynamoDB chooses Consistency during a network partition. What does Amazon Document DB do?.

A few example document DB I know are CouchDB and MongoDB. Both chose consistency over availability during the event of network issues between the internal database replication. I could not find information on Amazon Document DB. Any ideas or pointers?

Comment: Have you read the [Durability/Consistency/Isolation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/documentdb/latest/developerguide/how-it-works.html#durability-consistency-isolation) guide?

Comment: I believe DynamoDB chooses Availability, not Consistency